# Onclick listener object does not change when click | android

Tags: java, android

So  I have four buttons in a page and I want system randomly select one button at first and when user click on it, the system will randomly select another button again without duplicate until all the button has been clicked by user. But I don't know what is wrong with my code that it can only listen to the first button's action. Only when I click on the first button that selected by the system then it will do the actions.

Here is my code, thanks in advance:

```
Button bt1,bt2,bt3,bt4,bt5;
TextView text;
Random random = new Random();
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        bt1=findViewById(R.id.button);
        bt2=findViewById(R.id.button2);
        bt3=findViewById(R.id.button3);
        bt4=findViewById(R.id.button4);

        Button[]all={bt1,bt2,bt3,bt4};
        ArrayList<Button> arr_new = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Button i : all)
        {
            arr_new.add(i);
        }

        while(!arr_new.contains(bt5)) {
            bt5 = arr_new.get(random.nextInt(all.length));
            bt5.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            bt5.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                arr_new.remove(bt5);
                bt5 = arr_new.get(random.nextInt(arr_new.size()));

                bt5.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

            });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest avoid using a while loop (that keeps on running for nothing).

Instead, you can use a recursive function call.

1. Creating the buttons array:

```
bt1=findViewById(R.id.button);
bt2=findViewById(R.id.button2);
bt3=findViewById(R.id.button3);
bt4=findViewById(R.id.button4);

Button[]all={bt1,bt2,bt3,bt4};
ArrayList<Button> arr_new = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(all));
```

2. Shuffle the array

```
Collections.shuffle(arr_new);
```

3. Now that you have a randomly ordered array of buttons, you can simply take the first one (it was randomly picked to be the first...), wait for a click, remove it from the list and again.. take the first one, click, remove..
4. Let's define the recursive function. It calls itself until no more buttons left in the shuffled array:

```
void untilAllSelected(ArrayList<Button> buttons) {
    
    // Check if not more buttons - this means we clicked all of them..
    if (buttons.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }
    
    // Set the clicked button color
    buttons.get(0).setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    // Set a click listener on the first button
    buttons.get(0).setOnClickListener(v -> {
        // When clicked - remove the listener to avoid feature clicks
        v.setOnClickListener(null);
        
        // Remove the clicked button from the list
        buttons.remove(0);
        
        // Recursively call the function with the buttons list (which is now 1 button shorter)
        untilAllSelected(buttons);
    });
}
```

5. Last thing, call the recursive function. Here's the complete code:

```
Button bt1,bt2,bt3,bt4,bt5;
TextView text;
Random random = new Random();

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    bt1=findViewById(R.id.button);
    bt2=findViewById(R.id.button2);
    bt3=findViewById(R.id.button3);
    bt4=findViewById(R.id.button4);

     Button[]all={bt1,bt2,bt3,bt4};
     ArrayList<Button> arr_new = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(all));
     Collections.shuffle(arr_new);

     untilAllSelected(arr_new);
}

void untilAllSelected(ArrayList<Button> buttons) {
    if (buttons.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }

    buttons.get(0).setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    buttons.get(0).setOnClickListener(v -> {
        v.setOnClickListener(null);
        buttons.remove(0);
        untilAllSelected(buttons);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it does not match what I want. I wanted it to be the system random select one button and make the one background to be changed and user clicks on it then system again randomly select another button for the user to click but not user click on it then background changed. It is like a speed touch game.